# How to access the IntlProvider's locale and messages in a component?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-intl

So my index.js has something like this:

```
import trFi from './translations/fi_FI.json';
import trSv from './translations/sv_SE.json';

ReactDOM.render(
  <IntlProvider
    locale={my_locale}
    messages={{ fi: trFi, sv: trSv }[my_locale]}
  >
      <Root />
  </IntlProvider>
);
```

And `Root` has multiple sub components and all. Now how can I get the provided `locale` and `messages` in these sub components? I know I can pass them as props to `Root`, which again passes them down, but my tree is rather deep and it's a pain in the ass to maintain this.

Is it possible to access this `locale` and `messages` passed to `IntlProvider` in the subcomponents directly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As explained [in the docs here](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/wiki#formatting-data), you can use a HOC (High Order Component) to wrap your components where they need to access internationalized data provided by `<IntlProvider />` at the root of your component tree.

Also, you have to use the `<Formatted*>` components to actually use that data for display.

Here's an example from the docs above:

```
import React from 'react';
import { injectIntl, FormattedRelative } from 'react-intl';

const PostDate = ({ date, intl }) => (
    <span title={ intl.formatDate(date) }>
        <FormattedRelative value={ date }/>
    </span>
);

PostDate.propTypes = {
    date: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
    intl: intlShape.isRequired,
};

export default injectIntl(PostDate);
```

In addition to `format*` helpers, the config props, including `messages` and`locale` can also be accessed directly down the tree via the same component prop `intl` ([see the type definition `intlShape` here](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/wiki/API#injection-api)):

```
const { locale, messages } = this.props.intl;
```

Comment: Yeah the first link is what I originally followed through, but this particular use case requires me to translate `<input>`'s `placeholder` attribute, and thus I can't use the `<Formatted*>` components for this.

Comment: "The messages themselves can be accessed from the props of your components if you need direct access. This is documented in this example" I don't quite follow here, the example just uses the global `messages` object? I was particularly asking if it's possible to fetch the `message` object passed to `<IntlProvider>` in sub components, or if my only option is to forward it throught the whole tree as props

Comment: Wow yeah, I answered way too quickly, sorry! I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

When writing react with hooks you can use the `useIntl` hook to access the `intl` object.

```
import React from 'react'
import {useIntl, FormattedDate} from 'react-intl'

const FunctionComponent: React.FC<{date: number | Date}> = ({date}) => {
  const intl = useIntl()
  return (
    <span title={intl.formatDate(date)}>
      <FormattedDate value={date} />
    </span>
  )
}

export default FunctionComponent
```

(example taken from, and more info to be found at, https://formatjs.io/docs/react-intl/api/#useintl-hook )

Answer (score 1):

Yep, that is possible. Import the useIntl hook like this:

```
import { useIntl } from 'react-intl'

const MyComponent: = () => {
  const intl = useIntl()
  console.log('What you need is here: ', intl.locale)

  return (
    <>
      ...
    </>
  )
}

export default MyComponent
```